# Performance and scaleability for data access

Tags: asp.net, performance, entity-framework, ado.net, scalability

I have looked at a lot of answers but have not found a satisfactory answer.
Here is the problem. I need to create a web application. Technology will be based on Microsoft stack(ASP.NET 4, C#, SQL Server 2008). Infrastructure will be hosted on Amazon EC2.
I need to make a decision as to best way to access data.

1. Entity FrameWork
2. Plane old ADO.NET

At peak there can be about 100,000 people accessing this web site at one time. To achieve this scale and have a decent performance can Entity Framework be used or its better to fall back on ADO.NET? Is there performance issue with Entity framework Vs ADO.NET?

Any tips will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are building high traffic web site, you probably should work with simple Ado.net. But Micro-ORMs can be an option for you. For example SO uses a single file ORM dapper dot net. 
If you look Performce table you will see EntityFramework shouldnt be an option. Personally I like PetaPoco.

http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/03/30/How+I+learned+to+stop+worrying+and+write+my+own+ORM

```
 **Method**                                     **Duration**     
 Hand coded (using a SqlDataReader)         47ms 
 Dapper ExecuteMapperQuery<Post>            49ms 
 ServiceStack.OrmLite (QueryById)           50ms 
 PetaPoco                                   52ms    Can be faster 
 BLToolkit                                  80ms 
 SubSonic CodingHorror                      107ms 
 NHibernate SQL                             104ms 
 Linq 2 SQL ExecuteQuery                    181ms 
 Entity framework ExecuteStoreQuery         631ms
```

Comment: Thanks guys. This helps a lot. I guess Entity Framework is out. O am looking into dapper.At the end of the day ADP.NET is what I might fall back on. Its sad as I really like EF. But I guess cannot have cake and eat it too.

Comment: One of the biggest performance hits that EF takes is from generating views, and preparing queries. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx That said, if you look at updated info on this topic, you will find that EF5+ on .net 4.5 takes this into account by automatically compiling all queries which results in a significant boost in performance. See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/14/sneak-preview-entity-framework-5-0-performance-improvements.aspx. However you can still get this boost on EF4 by updating to 4.5, or just compiling queries manually.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework, LINQ2SQL and other OR mappers have a small run time penalty on the application server side. The penalty is however way below 1% in most real life applications.

As with most technologies (the do the same thing in different ways) the performance impact is not much depending on the technology, but on how you implement them. You can fail catastrophically with EF if you type a EF-query that translates in to several SQL-queries that loops over the database. But those cases are easy to spot and easy to fix.

Comment: In my experience, the penalty for EF, LINQ2SQL and other ORMs is much higher than 1% -- the combination of no async, dynamic SQL, no batching and seemingly inevitable chattiness is usually painful for large apps....